# How to definitely remove a file from my git local branch?

Tags: git, github

**Environment :**

Windows 10

I wanted to push some files on my remote master github repository. There was an issue with a file which is too large.

So I removed it with the command:

```
git rm modules/db.db
```

I made a commit and when I tried to push again my local branch to the master, I get again the same error message:

```
C:\Users\gauth\Documents\github\abc>git push origin master
Enumerating objects: 263, done.
Counting objects: 100% (263/263), done.
Delta compression using up to 6 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (262/262), done.
Writing objects: 100% (263/263), 49.93 MiB | 6.17 MiB/s, done.
Total 263 (delta 75), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (75/75), done.
remote: error: Trace: 68110557c386982431ba3a2ec8e09d4c9ee8400e835d0490d29c096b851007e1
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File modules/db.db is 144.78 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
To https://github.com/abc/abc.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/abc/abc.git'
```

I don't understand why git doesn't take this removal! Why does it still want to upload a removed file? Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: The trouble is that you are pushing multiple commits and they have the problem file still. One possibility: Try `git reset --soft origin/master`. Now commit and push. That way you are pushing just _one_ commit and it lacks the problem file. Of course you have also squashed your history so don't do it if that's not acceptable.

Comment: By the way, the very error message you quoted contains a link (http://git.io/iEPt8g) that tells you what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Files don't precisely exist in *branches*.  They exist inside *commits*—which are then contained within branches, so you can get from point Z back to point A, but you have to go through all the intermediate points first.

This is precisely your problem: the large file `modules/db.db` exists in a whole bunch of *commits* (or maybe in just *one* commit).  When you run `git rm` and then `git commit`, you make a *new* commit.  The *new* commit omits the file, but all the existing commits still exist, and still *contain* the file.

You must find all the *existing* commits that contain the large file, and fix them—which itself is impossible: no *existing commit* can be changed, ever: not by you, and not by Git itself.  So, that means you must find all the existing commits that contain the large file, and *throw them out entirely*.

If they have valuable data in them, you'll want to copy the valuable data *out* of those commits, into new-and-improved commits that are just like the originals, except that they omit this large file.  You'll then want to rearrange your existing branch *names* so that instead of finding the old commits—which are no good because they contain the large file—they find, instead, the *new and improved* commits.

If the old commits have no valuable data in them at all, you can just toss all of them out, and make a new final commit that stores the right files, and omits the large file.

See [How to remove/delete a large file from commit history in Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2100907/1256452)

Comment: Buried deep in that linked question is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61602985/184546) mentioning `git-filter-repo`, which maybe is the way to go nowadays.